# Retrofit 2 POST JSON Object with Response giving error code 400, message = nul

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to post user details to create new user in the database using POJO classes. The API accepts raw JSON as post requests.
The response that I am receiving is "Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=, url=my api url}"

I am using POJO class CreateUser to create details for my user and passing it to Retrofit API Interface

My API definition is as below, CreateUserResponse is the response POJO class to store the Retrofit Response

```
public interface APIDefinitions {
@POST("auth/register")
Call<CreateUserResponse> RegisterUser(@Body CreateUser createUser);
```

}

My Retrofit Client Setup Class:

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private final static String base_url = "https://url/";
private static RetrofitClient retrofitClient;
private static Retrofit retrofit;

HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
private RetrofitClient(){

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(base_url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
}


public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance(){
    if (retrofitClient == null)
        retrofitClient = new RetrofitClient();
    return retrofitClient;
}

public APIDefinitions getApi() {
    return retrofit.create(APIDefinitions.class);
}
```

}

Below is how I am making a new call and sending the POST request in my user activity

```
//                The below createUser object initialization is for testing purpose and thus hardcoded
            CreateUser user = new CreateUser(
                    "harshpalit",
                    "harshpalit@gmail.com",
                    "harshpalit",
                    "harshpalit",
                    "Harsh",
                    "Palit",
                    987845789);

            Call<CreateUserResponse> call = RetrofitClient
                    .getInstance()
                    .getApi()
                    .RegisterUser(user);

            Log.d("Request", call.request().body().contentType().toString());
            Log.d("Request", call.request().toString());
            call.enqueue(new Callback<CreateUserResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<CreateUserResponse> call, Response<CreateUserResponse> response) {
                    Log.d("Response from Server", response.raw().toString());
                    if (response.code()==400) {
                        Log.d("Error 400",response.errorBody().toString());
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    CreateUserResponse response1 = response.body();
                   Log.d("Response Message", response1.getMessage() + "Failed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<CreateUserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("Failed Log",t.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

My request call that is being sent:

> Request{method=POST,
> url=https://managed-dev-test.herokuapp.com/api/auth/register,
> tags={class
> retrofit2.Invocation=com.craftec.managed.API.APIDefinitions.RegisterUser()
> [com.craftec.managed.POJO.CreateUser@b2319f8]}}

The response :

Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=, url=https://managed-dev-test.herokuapp.com/api/auth/register}

It seems that everything is proper in place. Please help

Comment: Does the `base_url` in `RetrofitClient` has typo? ("https://url/" --> "https://")

Comment: It's not a typo, I replaced it with a placeholder for the purpose of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, test the API with PostMan or any other related applications and get the response.
After that create an appropriate POJO class for it.
And if everything went well it will fix your problem.

Verify the **CreateUserResponse** POJO Class

```
public class CreateUserResponse {

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Boolean success;

@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;

public Boolean getSuccess() {
return success;
}

public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
this.success = success;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}
}
```

If this didn't fix it then you have to check the **CreateUser** class.
Verify that you are passing the correct values for each field.

Comment: Thank you for your help. All my POJO Class are structured properly and I checked using postman it's giving proper response

Comment: Can you provide the response?

Comment: Not this one, I want from PostMan.

Comment: {
    "success": true,
    "message": "User registered successfully"
}

Comment: Hi, this woked out, the POJO CreateUserResponse didn't had 'scucess' as type boolean and thus mismatch was happening leading to bad request erro(400). Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm glad that you find the issue and worked for you.